# HB100 Doppler sensor calculation

Tags: sensor, microwave, calculation, 741-opamp

[image: Circuit-1]

[image: Circuit-2]

I have a question about the first circuit schematics.

I calculated the second circuit's fcutLow and fcutHigh frequencies like this:

f2CutHigh = 1/(2 * π * 1M * 100p) = 1.6 kHz

f2CutLow  = 1/(2 * π * 10k * 10μ) = 1.6 Hz

But for the first circuit:

> Blockquote [Why is such amplifier configuration chosen for HB100 microwave sensor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337529/why-is-such-amplifier-configuration-chosen-for-hb100-microwave-sensor)

I saw this calculation and I didn't understand it.

- Why is step 1 used like that (as I understood it, it is a passive high-pass filter)?
- Why do 2-3 or 4-5 calculate Fcutlow = 4.7μ-10k and FcutHigh =2.2n-1M with each other?
- Why did they use a voltage divider for the second-order op-amp?

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? Which calculation(s) did you not understand. Also you can use equations in your questions using latex format: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-a-math-formula-in-a-post

Comment: Why they used voltage divider or why first circuit they calculated cut off frequencies like that as I mentioned above for steps numerated circuit